# find the company which has more than 10 years of revenue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a table Company and CompanyHistory. CompanyHistory shows the revenue and year. The relation between company and company history is

A company has many company histories while company history belongs to company.

I need to find a number of companies who has revenue of more than 10 years. I could find only companies with revenue data with following query

```
CompanyHistory.where.not(revenue: 0).pluck(:company_id).uniq.count
```

How can i find based on year? I mean only those Companies with 10+ years of revenues data.

CompanyHistory has certain field

```
CompanyHistory(id: integer, company_id: integer, revenue: float, year: integer, month: integer, date: date, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try sub query like below.

```
CompanyHistory.where("revenue > 0 AND id in (select distinct id from company_histories where year <= #{10.years.ago.year})").distinct('company_id').count
```

If you need to get < 10 years, you need to use following one

```
CompanyHistory.where("revenue > 0 AND id in (select distinct id from company_histories where year > #{10.years.ago.year})").distinct('company_id').count
```

You can get more idea when you just copy paste the above statements in Rails console where you can see the exact SQL query executed.

I just used the current year for getting the data you have mentioned. Get distinct ids which have 10+ years revenue using sub query, using these ids do another query to get desired output. But these queries will be run one DB request though we used two queries.

Comment: i get error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "select distinct id from company_histories where year <= 2009"

Comment: @Serenity Sorry, edited the answer. Please try it now.

Comment: does this count the company's revenue of same year? I mean if there is multiple revenue in same year, then will it count just 1 or 2?

Comment: @Serenity It will be 1. Also it will get distinct count across year.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. can you make me a bit clear on year <= part, please? if i want companies with <10 years revenue data then should it be year >=? sorry i did not understand year part.

Comment: yeah i saw sql query where it is showing year <= 2009. I will now search for how can i use #{10.years.ago.year} in plain sql as well. Thanks a lot for your help